# Sorting of arraylist of multiple arraylists

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist of multiple arraylists like-

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al1=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

the arraylist contains the elements:

```
[[Total for all Journals, IOP, IOPscience, , , , , 86, 16, 70, 17, 8, 14, 6, 17, 19, 5], [2D Materials, IOP, IOPscience, 10.1088/issn.2053-1583, 2053-1583, , 2053-1583, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [Acta Physica Sinica (Overseas Edition), IOP, IOPscience, 10.1088/issn.1004-423X, 1004-423X, 1004-423X, , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [Advances in Natural Sciences: Nanoscience and Nanotechnology, IOP, IOPscience, 10.1088/issn.2043-6262, 2043-6262, , 2043-6262, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [Applied Physics Express, IOP, IOPscience, , 1882-0786, 1882-0778, 1882-0786, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now i want to sort the main arraylist. Main arraylist contains 5 inner arraylists.Now the sorting must be like the 7th element of every inner arraylist is compared which is integer and inner arraylists are arranged accorting to the value of their 7th element.

```
Collections.sort(al1, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
  @Override public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {
    return o1.get(7).compareTo(o2.get(7));
  }
});
```

Comment: Create your own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and use [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: I am trying to make own comparator but everytime i got wrong result.

Comment: Show us your code. Describe what you *think* it does. Show us the *intended* output. Show us the *actual* output of your code.

Comment: Plese [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27035435/edit) if you want to add code.

Comment: @monudwivedi Use [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) to parse your `String` as an integer, and compare the integers, not the `String`s.

Comment: @monudwivedi And arrays/collections/... are indexed from `0`, so if you want the 7th element, use `.get(6)`.

Comment: Sounds like you should use a class rather than a List with elements that have special significance at specific indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes in Java begin at `0`. The 7th element has the index `6`. Moreover, you have to convert the `String` to int in order to be properly compared.

Try this :

```
Comparator<ArrayList<String>> cmp = new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>()
{
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> a1, ArrayList<String> a2)
    {
        // TODO check for null value
        return new Integer(a1.get(6)).compareTo(new Integer(a2.get(6));
    }
};

Collections.sort(yourList, cmp);
```

Comment: I made a modification

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` is always better, than `new Integer`

Comment: Yes, but i wanted to keep an object to use compareTo